# Is it possible to use ReferenceStream (or something similar) in the current Pharo 2.0/3.0 release?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

We have an assignment to save our current project state using ReferenceStream.  The issue is, it appears to be deprecated past 1.x and I'm currently using 3.0. Is there a new implementation of this feature, perhaps by a different name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The replacement would be Fuel
Try to inquire about that package

Comment: If you use Fuel to materialize a ReferenceStream, you will get a FLBadSignature exception...

Comment: Well, I see no reason for a downvote here. Fuel may have a problem, but I'm not responsible of it, and problem or not, it's still the official replacement. Fuel has a issue tracker and Pharo has mailing lists, I hope you will help and report.

Comment: Oh, I get it, you want to read ReferenceStream output with Fuel? It's of course impossible like trying to read bzip2 output with gzip. You should first install Fuel into Pharo 1.0, read the ReferenceStream, write the Fuel, then go back to 3.0. It's going to be some work because I'm not sure that recent version of Fuel are maintained in 1.0. The alternative is to export ReferenceStream as an external package and reuse it in Pharo 3.0...